# MPI contigous type example gives fatal error

Tags: c, mpi

I am a beginner in MPI and I am following this link to learn: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/#Derived_Data_Types. In the end of the section, there is an example. I added the code here. The difference is just two `printf` functions in line 30  and 33.

The problem is the code doesn't work. It gives a `Fatal error` such that:

```
MPI_Send(173): MPI_Send(buf=0x7fff20072940, count=1, dtype=USER<contig>, dest=4, tag=1, 
MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPI_Send(98).: Invalid rank has value 4 but must be nonnegative and less than 4
```

I think it tries to send processor 4, but it does not exist. Why is it doing that? 
Also, when I remove my `printf` functions, the program doesn't show anything and I just see the cursor of command line.

I compile it with:

```
mpicc mpi_contigous_data.cpp -o contigous_type
```

I run it with:

```
mpirun -np 4 ./contigous_type
```

The code is here:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int numtasks, rank, source=0, dest, tag=1, i;
float a[SIZE][SIZE] =
  {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
   5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0,
   9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0,
   13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0};
float b[SIZE];

MPI_Status stat;
MPI_Datatype rowtype;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

MPI_Type_contiguous(SIZE, MPI_FLOAT, &rowtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&rowtype);

if (numtasks == SIZE) {
 if (rank == 0) {
  for (i=0; i<numtasks; i++)
   printf("From root, sending to %d\n",i);
   MPI_Send(&a[i][0], 1, rowtype, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
 }
printf("My rank is %d,waiting message\n",rank);
MPI_Recv(b, SIZE, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
printf("rank= %d  b= %3.1f %3.1f %3.1f %3.1f\n",
     rank,b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]);
}
else
 printf("Must specify %d processors. Terminating.\n",SIZE);

MPI_Type_free(&rowtype);
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: You should be very careful when adding statements to the body of a `for` loop. Single-statement bodies do not need to be enclosed in a block `{ ... }`, but anything else must be, otherwise only the first statement will be part of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code to get the expected result. I changed sends and receive to non-blocking versions. Here my last version for the example in https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/#Derived_Data_Types.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
int numtasks, rank, source=0, dest, tag=1, i;
float a[SIZE][SIZE] =
     {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
      5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0,
      9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0,
      13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0};
float b[SIZE];

MPI_Status stat[SIZE];
MPI_Request send_req[SIZE], recv_req[SIZE];
MPI_Datatype rowtype;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

MPI_Type_contiguous(SIZE, MPI_FLOAT, &rowtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&rowtype);

if (numtasks == SIZE) {
  if (rank == 0) {
   for (i=0; i<numtasks; i++) {
   printf("From root, sending to %d\n",i);
   // MPI_Send was changed to non-blocking version
   MPI_Isend(&a[i][0], 1, rowtype, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD,&send_req[i]);
 }
// root waits until sending all messages
MPI_Waitall(numtasks-1,&send_req[1],&stat[1]);
 }
// I changed MPI_Recv to non-blocking version
MPI_Irecv(&b, SIZE, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &recv_req[0]);
// A processor also waits for request to end
MPI_Wait(&recv_req[0],&stat[0]);
printf("rank= %d  b= %3.1f %3.1f %3.1f %3.1f\n",
 rank,b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]); }
else
 printf("Must specify %d processors. Terminating.\n",SIZE);

MPI_Type_free(&rowtype);
MPI_Finalize(); }
```

I compile and run with:

```
mpicc mpi_contigous_data.cpp -o contigous_type
mpirun -np 4 ./contigous_type
```

That gives the result:

```
From root, sending to 0
From root, sending to 1 
From root, sending to 2
From root, sending to 3
rank= 1  b= 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0
rank= 2  b= 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0
rank= 3  b= 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0
rank= 0  b= 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0
```

Comment: You never wait for `send_req[0]`. Technically the MPI library is not required to even start the send operation before the request is tested or waited on. In your case it works since waiting on the non-blocking receive in rank 0 also progresses the non-blocking send (as per the MPI standard requirement), but still your program is non-conformant. You also don't have to match non-blocking sends with non-blocking receives - it is perfectly ok to send with `MPI_Isend` and receive with `MPI_Recv`.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine without wait functions. Also, I changed `MPI_Irecv` to `MPI_Recv`. If i change `MPI_Isend` to `MPI_Send`, the program just waits. Is it because proc(rank=0) waits for the result of sending messages?

Comment: Rank 0 first sends a message to itself. Therefore a blocking send might put the program into a deadlock, especially when the message size exceeds the eager limit.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that rank numbering starts at 0. So if you start your program like this:

```
mpirun -np 4 ./contigous_type
```

Your ranks will be 0, 1, 2, 3. There is no 4.

More specifically for your problem though, You need to add the curly braces around your for loop on line 29. You're executing the print statement 4 times and the `MPI_Send` once. Using a good editor that will autoindent for you is very helpful here.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int numtasks, rank, source=0, dest, tag=1, i;
float a[SIZE][SIZE] =
  {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0,
   5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0,
   9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0,
   13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0};
float b[SIZE];

MPI_Status stat;
MPI_Datatype rowtype;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

MPI_Type_contiguous(SIZE, MPI_FLOAT, &rowtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&rowtype);

if (numtasks == SIZE) {
 if (rank == 0) {
  for (i=0; i<numtasks; i++) { /*<--- HERE!*/
   printf("From root, sending to %d\n",i);
   MPI_Send(&a[i][0], 1, rowtype, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  } /*<--- HERE!*/
 }
printf("My rank is %d,waiting message\n",rank);
MPI_Recv(b, SIZE, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &stat);
printf("rank= %d  b= %3.1f %3.1f %3.1f %3.1f\n",
     rank,b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]);
}
else
 printf("Must specify %d processors. Terminating.\n",SIZE);

MPI_Type_free(&rowtype);
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

There are plenty of other issues in your code though. I'm not going to fix all of them here because that wouldn't be very helpful to you. The most obvious thing is that your sends and receives don't match up. You have every process sending 4 messages but only receiving one.

Comment: It's only rank 0 that sends 4 messages and then each rank (including 0) receives one of them - a naïve implementation of `MPI_SCATTER`. Can't believe that the folks from LLNL have provided such a terrible example that relies on small sends being buffered or eagerly sent.

Comment: thanks.I don't use an editor that's why i didn't see the missing braces. Also, the root just sends to other 4 processors and they receive the results.